# How to continuously paint on a Canvas in Flutter after a delay of couple of seconds

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a set of Offsets defined. All I want is to draw these Offsets on a Canvas after a delay. This is to show the user the progress of the drawing. How can I do the same. Here is my code. But it errors out saying "Object has been disposed" at the drawPath line.

```
class ReplayPainter extends CustomPainter {
  List<PathData> strokes = new List<PathData>();

  ReplayPainter(this.strokes);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    print(strokes.length);
    for (PathData stroke in strokes) {
      Paint strokePaint = new Paint();
      strokePaint.strokeWidth = stroke.strokeWidth;
      strokePaint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
      strokePaint.strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round;
      strokePaint.strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
      strokePaint.color = stroke.strokeColor;

      Path strokePath = new Path();
      strokePath.addPolygon(stroke.offsets, false);
      Timer _timer = new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
        canvas.drawPath(strokePath, strokePaint);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }

}
```

The PathData has the Offsets in it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have to use the AnimationController. I was able to do it after reading the below two part tutorial.

https://medium.com/flutter-io/zero-to-one-with-flutter-43b13fd7b354

https://medium.com/flutter-io/zero-to-one-with-flutter-part-two-5aa2f06655cb